# Key management in GCP for storing private key for client tls certificate

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, pkcs#12, google-cloud-kms

We've recently decided to try to use KMS (Key management) in GCP for storing private keys that the organization has.

I stumbled upon an issue when I tried to move the private key and password to key management where they are a part of a .p12 that we use in a key store to communicate with an external third provider.

```
        val pkcs12KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
            .apply { load(ByteArrayInputStream(certificateContent), certPassword.toCharArray()) }

        val pkcs12KeyManager = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())
            .apply { init(pkcs12KeyStore, certPassword.toCharArray()) }

        val sslContext = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .keyManager(pkcs12KeyManager)
            .build()
```

Is what we do when we have access to the private key and password in the application. Is there a way to achieve this when the private key is in Key management in GCP?

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me tell you that unless they are necessary for backwards compatibility, GCP does not recommend “P12” service account keys.In the other hand, what you need to do is:

1.- Download “.p12” key (a) and convert to “pem”.

a)

```
$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create svc_account.p12 \
--iam-account=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL \
--key-file-type=p12
```

b)

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in svc_account.p12  \
-nocerts -nodes \
-passin pass:notasecret | openssl rsa -out privkey.pem`
```

2.- Create ImportJob.

```
export IMPORT_JOB=saimporter
export VERSION=1
$ gcloud beta kms import-jobs create $IMPORT_JOB \
--location $LOCATION \
--keyring $KEYRING_NAME \
--import-method rsa-oaep-3072-sha1-aes-256 \
--protection-level hsm
$ gcloud kms import-jobs describe $IMPORT_JOB \
--location $LOCATION \
--keyring $KEYRING_NAME
```

3.- Format “.pem” key for import.

```
$ openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -inform PEM \
-outform DER     -in privkey.pem  \
-out formatted.pem
```

4.- Via importJob, import the formatted key to KMS.

```
$ gcloud kms keys create $KEY_NAME \
--keyring=$KEYRING_NAME --purpose=asymmetric-signing \
--default-algorithm=rsa-sign-pkcs1-2048-sha256 \
--skip-initial-version-creation --location=$LOCATION \
--protection-level=hsm
$ gcloud kms keys versions import   \
--import-job $IMPORT_JOB   --location $LOCATION  \
--keyring $KEYRING_NAME   --key $KEY_NAME   \
--algorithm rsa-sign-pkcs1-2048-sha256  \
--target-key-file formatted.pem
```

5.- Then “.p12” and “.pem” files should be deleted files from disk.

As a reference, you can use the following information regarding your specific situation [Import Service Account Private Key to KMS (SA -> KMS)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-kms-based-service-accounts-for-authentication-and-signedurls-be2d785ed9ff). Plus, this official GCP’s information can be useful for you now and in the future [Creating service account keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys). Finally, for the Google Auth library, the Google Auth options that GCP got and how to handle them [Interface GoogleAuthOptions](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/google-auth-library/googleauthoptions).

Comment: Hi there, the point for us is to avoid having to create the key by ourselves. So we want to create the private key in GCP, and then use that to create a CSR and then construct a .p12 out of everything. 

I've managed to do everything except the final part where you're supposed to construct the .p12 to setup the ssl client connection. Ideally I would like to be able to set the key in KMS as the keystore when creating the TLS, but I've not found a way to do so.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: After a deep research and investigation, I can tell you that I haven't found any GCP’s documentation that enlists steps to achieve that. So maybe it is entirely impossible to be done with the KMS APIs available at the moment.

On the other hand, it is not GCP’s official documentation but I found an implementation example in GitHub, it looks like it can help you but I haven’t tested it yet. https://github.com/mattes/google-cloud-kms-csr